# NullPointerException while PDF to image conversion

Tags: java, image, pdf, nullpointerexception, pdfbox

While I was playing around with pdfbox 1.7.0 (apache) I came across a `NullPointerException`. I can't figure out what the hack is wrong with my code. You can see the full stacktrace of the `Exception` at http://pastebin.com/XEuv7VmU and the code here: http://pastebin.com/vJYBwWtq .

I just want to convert every page of a PDF into an image (`BufferedImage`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either I am missing something obvious or there is a bug in the library. `Type3StreamParser` extending `PDFStreamEngine` has the following method:

```
public Image createImage( COSStream type3Stream ) throws IOException
{
    processStream( null, null, type3Stream );
    return image.createImage();
}
```

it calls `processStream()` in the base class defined as follows:

```
public void processStream( PDPage aPage, PDResources resources, COSStream cosStream ) throws IOException
{
    graphicsState = new PDGraphicsState(aPage.findCropBox());
    //...
}
```

Clearly this code will always throw NPE. If you aren't misusing the API somehow, consider [reporting an issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX).

Comment: Okay thank you, thats what I found in the code, too so I'm not the only one who points that as an issue. I'll report it to apache, thank you!